# Eclipse SVN - Checkout after compare a.k.a. how to checkout small changes only

Tags: eclipse, svn

I've compared a project in my workspace to the "latest from the SVN repository".  There's a few files changed.  However, I know from experience that if I checkout, I'll have to download the whole darn thing again.

How can I checkout just the compared changes?  It feels like I'm missing a big concept here...the link between checking out just revisions vs. the whole project.  Actually, that's my main question - how to checkout/update small changes only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  I was missing the "Team Synchronizing" aspect of things as detailed here:

http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/subclipse/

> To synchronize resources, right click on a project and select Team >
>   Synchronize with   Repository

Apparently that's just to view changes.  The functionality I was looking for was "Team > Update to HEAD".